# Android on Samsung s5230 star (for C++)

Tags: c++, android

First of all, i will explain what i want to do, maybe there is a simpler way.So, i have a Samsung s5230 star, and i'm a C++ programmer.Bad combination, considering that for my phone there is only Java support and documentation.So this is mainly why i want to switch to android (and because i'm a computer geek and i'm curious how can you install a OS on a phone, lol :)) )
So, my first question is : If i change the OS (to Android), could i have a chance in making some C++ code run on my Samsung?If yes, please lead me to some (detailed, noob friendly :) ) indications on how to do it.
And, the second one (important even if the first one is not true) : Can i install Android on Samsung s5230 star ?If so, please, also, lead me to some noob-friendly info on the install of Android on my phone (or any phone).

As a bonus (you can ignore this, but i didn't want to make another useless topic about it), are there any "secret combinations" on the Samsung s5230 ?Like if i'd want to do more than just speak on the phone...like some way to acces the equivalent of BIOS, just to goof around with the phone :)

Sorry for asking three questions in one topic, if you have an answer for any of them, please post it.Thanks :)

Comment: I think you will find it easier to learn to program in java. It really should not be much of a jump.

Answer (score 1):

There was this project that was published for a while. I haven't ever tried it out, but [if you want to, you can download it here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5FWN-33x_RM). For the codes you can google around, one that works with every Samsung device is *#0*# e.g test mode. Also, if you shut the phone off and hold power and Vol - buttons simultaneously, it will enter a "DOWNLOAD" mode. (the only phones with UEFI are those with Windows pre-installed)

Answer (score 0):

There is the Android NDK, which lets you develop for the Android OS using C++. See this link for details: [NDK developer site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html). If you come from a C++ background, picking up Java is probably more trivial than wrestling with the NDK.